# Android exclude jar from aar, there are classes.jar and lint.jar in appcompat-1.2.0.aar

Tags: android, androidx, lint

Is there a way to exclude jar from aar? there are classes.jar and lint.jar in appcompat-1.2.0.aar . I want to exclude lint.jar when I **implmentation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'**

when I place **implmentation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'** to build gradle , my customized Lint rules will donot work. Because there is a lint.jar in appcomat.aar, so I want exclude lint.jar from appcomat.aar.

[image]

Because `lint` is just a jar in appcompat.aar, There is no lint dependency in `pom.xml`, So I cannot use blow code to exclude `lint.jar` :

```
implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0') {
   exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat', module: 'lint'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat', module: 'lint'
}
```

in your app level build.gradle file.
This basically excludes some of the modules inside the libraries which you do not need to use.

Group specifies the package name of the dependency you have imported, and module specifies the particular module that you wish to exclude.

Comment: Thank you for your help, But it did not work, lint.jar is not a `module`，It's just a jar file packed into appcompat.aar. Because there is no lint dependency in `pom.xml`, So we canot exclude it with `exclude module: 'lint'`

Comment: @Chiclaim Did you find the answer?

Comment: Hey @Chiclaim, can you show the error you are facing now?